# ZSH autolearn completition plugin

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

Is there something like "autolearn" command/plugin for zsh?

By this I mean when I type `command option option1 ...` and zsh don't know about options for this particular command I want zsh to remember those options for future autocompletition so when I type `command <tab>` in future zsh completes with `option1`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's anything like that present at the moment. Try searching for a plugin for a particular application instead, if it's widely used, high chance someone already wrote a plugin.

Alternatively, you can always write your own completion for your application and make it into a plugin:

Read up on it:

http://bewatermyfriend.org/p/2012/003/

http://www.linux-mag.com/id/1106/

Answer (score 0):

[zsh-autosuggestions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions) offers type-ahead completion.

For example, typing

```
command option
com <tab>
```

will offer `mand option` as a completion after the cursor in a muted gray color. The suggestion can be accepted by moving cursor through it.